# How to modify a single item in l3seq/l3clist

Tags: expl3, latex3

How can I modify a single item in l3seq or l3clist, just as a normal "array" in other programming languages? Like this: `a[n] = x`.

`\seq_item:Nn` may leave a "right value", but how to get a "left value" that can be changed?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to use a `property` list, although not as performaing as the other ones (according to the manual)

Comment: Adding to the left or right is possible, of course, but changing a particular element is not possible directly. You have to 'cut' the seq/clist into pieces, pop the relevant item from one side of the pieces and put the new element again to one of the pieces, then glue them together again...

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest to use `seq` or `clist` 'variables' to provide array - like functionality.

The `property` list is very powerful, although not as fast as `\seq`, but allows for changing elements directly, by applying key/values. The `key` is the number of the array element here, the value is the cell value of the array. However, `property` lists can be used as hashes as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_stonezeng_array_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillarray}{+m}{
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \prop_gput:NVn \g_stonezeng_array_prop {\l_tmpa_int }{##1}
  }
  \group_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ChangeElement}{m+m}{
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_stonezeng_array_prop {#1}{ #2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\RemoveElement}{m}{
  \prop_gremove:Nn \g_stonezeng_array_prop {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showarray}{}{
  \prop_map_inline:Nn  \g_stonezeng_array_prop {
    a[##1]~=##2\par

  }

}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fillarray{20,19,18}

\showarray

\ChangeElement{3}{21}


\showarray


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a sequence or clist has been set, it can only be modified by “popping” the leftmost or rightmost item, which means removing it and storing it in a token list variable; the functions are

```
\seq_pop_left:NN
\seq_pop_right:NN
\clist_pop_left:NN
\clist_pop_right:NN
```

and their global counterparts (with `gpop` instead of `pop`); the global variety will only globally remove the item, but the assignment to the token list variable is always local.

In order to modify an item in a sequence you need to rebuild it. A possible implementation follows

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonezeng_change_seq_item:Nnn
 {% #1 = sequence, #2 = index, #3 = the new item
  \__stonezeng_change_item:NNnn \seq_set_eq:NN #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonezeng_gchange_seq_item:Nnn
 {% #1 = sequence, #2 = index, #3 = the new item
  \__stonezeng_change_item:NNnn \seq_gset_eq:NN #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__stone_change_item:NNnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N #2 }
   {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } = { #3 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq { #4 }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq { \seq_item:Nn #2 { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  #1 #2 \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq
 }
```

A full test

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonezeng_change_seq_item:Nnn
 {% #1 = sequence, #2 = index, #3 = the new item
  \__stonezeng_change_seq_item:NNnn \seq_set_eq:NN #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonezeng_gchange_seq_item:Nnn
 {% #1 = sequence, #2 = index, #3 = the new item
  \__stonezeng_change_seq_item:NNnn \seq_gset_eq:NN #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__stonezeng_change_seq_item:NNnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N #2 }
   {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } = { #3 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq { #4 }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq { \seq_item:Nn #2 { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  #1 #2 \l__stone_zeng_temp_seq
 }

%%% test

\seq_new:N \l_stone_zeng_test_seq
\seq_new:N \g_stone_zeng_test_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_stone_zeng_test_seq { a, b, c, d }

\stonezeng_change_seq_item:Nnn \l_stone_zeng_test_seq { 3 } { z }

\seq_show:N \l_stone_zeng_test_seq

\group_begin:
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_stone_zeng_test_seq { a, b, c, d }

\stonezeng_gchange_seq_item:Nnn \g_stone_zeng_test_seq { 4 } { u }
\group_end:

\seq_show:N \g_stone_zeng_test_seq

\stop
```

The output on the console:

```
The sequence \l_stone_zeng_test_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {b}
>  {z}
>  {d}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \seq_show:N \l_stone_zeng_test_seq

? 
The sequence \g_stone_zeng_test_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {b}
>  {c}
>  {u}.
<recently read> }

l.49 \seq_show:N \g_stone_zeng_test_seq

?
```

One could easily add a test for the index to point to an integer beyond the current length of the sequence.